# How do I calculate sum of (2i+1)! using while loop?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, loops, while-loop

I'm writing console program in visual studio now.
My program should calculate the sum of following series:

```
1!+3!+5!+...+(2N+1)!,
```

where `N` is integer number greater then **0** (user should enter N first).

Unfortunately, I only can calculate sum of `1!+2!+3!+...(N)!`

```
/* Calculates sum of 1!+2!+3!+...+(N)! */

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int i=1, n, fact = 1, sum = 0;

    cout<<"Enter n";
    cin >> n;

    while(i <= n)
    {
        fact = fact * i;
        i++;
        sum = sum + fact;
    }

    cout<<"Sum is "<<sum<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

So how do I make my program to calculate the sum of

```
1!+3!+5!+...+(2N+1)!
```

Comment: Each time you're adding 1 by using `i++`, what would you need to add each time to get only odd numbers?

Comment: @MorphingDragon Well, if I rewrite it as 'i+2', knowing that i = 1 to get odd numbers, then I get wrong output.

Comment: Yes, that's because your factorial calculations won't include the even numbers. See my answer for how to deal with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as

```
while(i <= 2*n+1)
{
    fact = fact * i;
    if (i%2)
        sum = sum + fact;
    i++;
}
```

You want to allow the loop to iterate every time, so that your multiplications include the even numbers as well as the odd numbers (otherwise the second term would be `3*1`, not `3*2*1`); but it's only when you're looking at an odd number that you want to add to the total.

The alternative is to loop only on odd numbers, but each time to multiply by the current number and its predecessor:

```
while(i <= 2*n+1)
{
    fact = fact * i * (i>1 ? i-1 : 1);
    sum = sum + fact;
    i+=2;
}
```

This is a little more complicated. You're now looping just over odd numbers (because of the `i+=2`, so you need at each stage to multiply by `i` and by `i-1`. But you need to be careful on the first step: when `i==1`, you don't want to multiply by 0! So we need a ternary expression to make sure this doesn't happen.

Or we could start from `i=3`:

```
int i=3, sum=1, fact=1;
while(i <= 2*n+1)
{
    fact = fact * i * (i-1);
    sum = sum + fact;
    i+=2;
}
```

This now works as expected, but we need to initialize `sum` to `1` because the loop now misses off the case where `i==1`. Perhaps this is cleaner.

**But** please note that you will not manage to get very far before you hit an `int` overflow! You will get a little further with `long long`, but even so, factorials are huge, and you'll want to use an arbitrary size integer class by the time you hit `n==10` or so (the 10 is an estimate--I haven't calculated it).

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is really helpful. But is there another way of doing this? I mean, not using `if(i%2)` but using another loop?

Comment: @KiberPrestupnik I've added some extra things to show you how to avoid that.